# What is "Cresol Soap"?

Tags: nomenclature, identification

I recently came across a suggestion in an old (first published 1893) book that a solution of ~1% cresol soap in water could be used as a way to store a particular kind of root without allowing it to dry out or rot.

I've tried searching, but have been unable to determine what cresol soap might be. The closest I can find are several shady poorly-translated websites selling Lysol as cresol soap, or possibly a mixture of the two.

Does anyone have a clue what this book could be referring to?

Comment: Best guess is that it's just cresol (not sure which isomer). Phenol itself is considered an antiseptic agent that was the substance put forward by Joseph Lister for sterilization before surgery: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenol#History

Comment: @orthocresol just felt like tagging you here, no reason ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- According to an 1894 tract with the title [Merck's Market Report and Pharmaceutical Journal: An Independent Monthly Magazine Devoted to the Professional and Commercial Interests of the Druggist, Volume 3](https://books.google.com/books?id=ITxHAQAAMAAJ), "cresol soap" was also called "crelium" or "crelium soap".
- The google n-gram viewer [suggests](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cresol+soap&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccresol%20soap%3B%2Cc0) that "cresol soap" is a historical term, whose usage began in the 1890s, peaked dramatically during World War I and its immediate aftermath, and declined substantially afterwards.
- A [1915 British medical report](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2301696/) argues for using cresol soap as a vermin control agent in troop populations.  It gives a recipe as:

  1. 10 gallons of water
  2. 1.5 pounds of soft soap
  3. Jeyes' fluid 1.5 ounces

  This raises the question of what "Jeyes' fluid" is. Amazingly, [Jeyes' Fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeyes_Fluid) is apparently still a commercial product, and contains a mixture of [4-chloro-*m*-cresol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-Chlorocresol), isopropanol, terpineol, and "tar acids".
- "Cresol soaps" are apparently still an item of commerce somewhere in the world, as a [2011 applications report form an analytical equipment vendor](http://www.agilent.com/cs/library/applications/A00965.pdf) illustrates the analysis of a "cresol soap" sample, although a specific source is sadly not mentioned.  The primary detected constituents were *m*-cresol and *p*-cresol.

I suspect there are many other recipes that involve mixing soap, water, and crude cresol preparations of various kinds.  In the era of cresol soap's invention and popularity, coal was far more ubiquitous than now, and the cresol sources were probably crude fractions of distilled coal tar that were enriched in various isomers of cresol.  In those days awareness of potential toxicity from cresols was also not as developed as now.  The "tar acids" in Jeyes' fluid probably include a variety of cresol isomers.

Comment: Toxicity is kinda par for the course in a disinfectant -- they presumably started using it because it kills stuff, and it kills stuff because it's toxic. And, hey, in those days, they were so busy dying early of arsenic poisoning that they wouldn't have noticed the ffects of the cresols.

Comment: Excellent research! I would go ahead and accept this now, except it seems odd to me that an American writing in the 1980's would refer to a product from the early 1900's. I'm going to leave this open for a bit just to see if there is some other niche use of the term neither of us were able to find that another user could be aware of.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have accepted this answer long ago. Not sure how it slipped my mind so long, but I suppose better late than never.